# Implications of defining a struct inside a function vs outside?

Tags: go

Are there any implications (GC churn, performance, or otherwise) to defining a `struct` inside a function vs. having it defined outside? For example:

```
type Outside struct {
  Foo string `json:"foo"`
}

func SomeFunc(b []byte) error {
  outside := Outside{}

  if err := json.NewDecoder(b).Decode(&outside); err != nil {
    return err
  }

  ...
}
```

vs.

```
func SomeFunc(b []byte) error {

  type inside struct {
    Foo string `json:"foo"`
  }

  if err := json.NewDecoder(b).Decode(&inside); err != nil {
    return err
  }

  ...
}
```

Would there be any situation where one is preferred over the other?

Answer (score 29):

To me the main drawback for a type defined in a function is that you cannot define methods on that type.

See this example https://play.golang.org/p/cgH01cRwDv6:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    type MyType struct {
        Name string
    }

    // You cannot define a method on your type
    // defined in a function, can you?

    func (m MyType) String() string {
      return m.Name
    }

    m := MyType{Name: "Hello, World!"}
    fmt.Println(m)
}
```

The above example will fail with the error `prog.go:15:27: expected ';', found 'IDENT' string (and 1 more errors)`.

Answer (score 21):

There is no performance difference – it's only a difference of scope (i.e., where the type definition can be seen). If you only need the type within a single function, it's fine to define it there.

As others have noted, if you define a type at the package level (i.e., outside of a function) with a name beginning with a capital letter, it will be exported (i.e., visible outside the package). If the name doesn't begin with a capital letter, it will only be visible within the package.

Answer (score 10):

My understanding is the difference is just in accessibility.

- A struct defined starting with an **upper case** letter will be exportable, meaning it can be accessed from other packages.
- A struct defined starting with a **lower case** letter can be accessed from anything within the same package but not externally.
- A struct defined in a function **inline** can only be accessed/initialized by that function.

Answer (score 3):

For me I once defined a struct inside a function for marshalling JSON byte array `([]byte)` into the struct instance, and extract a message from the instance.

Obviously it is not required to define the struct. I could have extracted the message by marshalling the JSON byte array into `interface{}` and then cast recursively to get the required message.

By defining the struct, extraction of the message becomes very easy :)

```
    var errDetail struct {
        Message string `json:"message"`
        Success bool   `json:"success"`
    }
    
    json.Unmarshal(*bytes, &errDetail)
    
    if errDetail.Message == "" {
        fmt.Println("error message is not present")
        return nil
    }
    return errDetail.Message
```

Answer (score 2):

The scope is different, you can check in Golang spec [here](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Declarations_and_scope):

Most related parts are:

> Go is lexically scoped using blocks:
>
> The scope of an identifier denoting a constant, type, variable, or function (but not method) declared at top level (outside any function) is the package block.
>
> The scope of a type identifier declared inside a function begins at the identifier in the TypeSpec and ends at the end of the innermost containing block.

And if you use `go tool compile -S -N hello.go` to check the generated assembly code, you can spot the names of type defined in package level and names of type defined inside function are different.

**Package level**

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type Point struct {
    X, Y int
}

func main() {
    fmt.Printf("%v\n", Point{X: 1, Y: 2})
}
```

Then try to compile and find this line: `type."".Point SRODATA size=144`.

**Inside function**

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)


func main() {
    type Point struct {
        X, Y int
    }
    fmt.Printf("%v\n", Point{X: 1, Y: 2})
}
```

Then try to find this line: `type.*"".Point·1 SRODATA size=56`

Than means, they just got different names after compiled.

Answer (score 1):

As others have mentioned its all about limit the variables scope. If you are going to use a struct inside a function, you could also use an anonymous struct.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {

    m := struct {
        greeting string
        name     string
    }{
        greeting: "hello",
        name:     "world",
    }

    fmt.Printf("%v %v\n", m.greeting, m.name)
}
```

If you're only planing to use the struct inside the function you can define the fields of the struct and assign values to them right away.

Answer (score 0):

For Konrad Kleine's problem, you can still do it with some workaround like this
https://play.golang.org/p/50yv66LUNRt

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    type MyType struct {
        Name string
        String func() string
    }
    InitMyType := func(m *MyType) {
        m.String = func() string {
            return m.Name
        }
        return 
    }
    
    m := MyType{Name: "Hello, World!"}
    initMyType(&m)
    
    fmt.Println(m.String())
}
```

I agree the difference is just accessibility.

But this is still very useful, especially what you want is only a temp struct, or when you do unit test, there are many similar struct like args, test case in a package, you won't need bother to name them one by one.